# curl connection works in Postman and Reqbin but not in php page

Tags: php, web-services, curl, php-curl

I'm developing a web application in php and I need to connect to an ERP via Web Services method. I tried to setup my connection using postman and reqbin, then I take the code generated and copied it into a simple php page.

In postman and reqbin the code works, I obtain the 200 response code and the content I ask for. If I put the code generated by postman in a php file...this is the result:

**Failed to connect to 93.145.226.114 port 8881: Connection refused**

The *CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE* is 0
The *curl_errno* method returns 7

I also tried to exclude all hidden headers that Postman includes by default.
Any idea of how to fix it?

Here is the code generated by postman:

```
<?php

$curl = curl_init();

curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
  CURLOPT_URL => 'http://93.145.226.114:8881/trz/giacenze?codArticolo=',
  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
  CURLOPT_ENCODING => '',
  CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
  CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
  CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
  CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
  CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => 'GET',
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'depositante: 01094',
    'Host: albatros.linktotheworld.eu',
    'Authorization: Basic TmV3c2l0ZTA6QWxiYTY1YUE='
  ),
));

$response = curl_exec($curl);

echo curl_getinfo($curl, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE) . '<br/>';
echo curl_errno($curl) . '<br/>';
echo curl_error($curl) . '<br/>';
curl_close($curl);
echo $response;
```

In the header, 'depositante' identify the client, and 'Host' is the url where is my web page.
I also tried to put out the port number from the URL (and set it by the CURLOPT_PORT method), but I get same result.
Thanks in advance to those who will help me.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by myself.

I discovered that my hosting have the port 8881 closed; they give me a list of available ports. The I asked to the web service manager to change the listening to another, and it all works!